# Char comparison in Firebird SQL

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have an SQL statement in which an IF condition checks if 'A' is smaller than 'B' but it returns False example:

```
x='A'
Y='B'
If X>Y then
 ......
```

but it never works!

Comment: 1) You've set lowercase `x` and then are mistakenly checking for uppercase `X`, and 2) you've got your boolean operators backwards - 'A' less than 'B' is `X < Y` in this case.

Comment: Please show your actual code. Firebird SQL statements don't support `IF`, and as HFBrowning points out, you have your comparison mixed up.

Comment: You're Right, but my probleme was in fact, how to compare a range of alphabet chars including zero, here's the solution that I made :                    if ( (X between 'A' and 'Z' and :Y='0') or (X between 'A' and 'Z' and :Y between 'A' and 'Z' and X>:Y)   ) then
        begin
            .........
        end;                                                                                                                                                     Thanks for everyone .